# JQuery validation plugin not supported by any IE or Firefox < 3.6 but works fine for Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, validation, firefox, submit

This is my first post and will appreciate if I can get the solution from you asap. Thanks in advance. :)

I am using JQuery validation plugin in my application. I have a signup form and uses .submit() method to submit the form. But when I try to submit the same form from Mozilla or IE,it submits the form but doesn't go through the validation. So in short w/o validation, I am getting garbage data in y DB.

I am attaching my .JS file and please have to look and let me know if I am doing something wrong.

home.js

//Validation rules

```
    $('#signup-form').validate({

        rules: {
            'firstname':       { required:  true },
            'lastname':        { required:  true },
            'email':           { required:  true,
                                 email:     true,
                                 remote:  { url:  siteurl+'ajax/checkemail',
                                            type: 'post' }},
. 
.
.
.
messages: {
            'firstname':       { required:  'Please enter your first name' },
            'lastname':        { required:  'Please enter your last name' },
            'email':           { required:  'Please enter your email address',
                                 email:     'Your email address is invalid',
                                 remote:    'The email you chose is already in use' },

    .
    .
    .       
    errorLabelContainer: $(".fail-message")

    });.
```

//Click sign up OK button

```
            $("#signup-ok-btn").click(function(){           
              $("#signup-form").submit();
              return false;         
             });
```

//Signup form submit

```
     $('#signup-form').submit(function(){

        //If the form is invalid
        if ($('#signup-form').valid()){             
            return true;                                    
        } else {                
            //Show errors
            $('#signup-form-fail').fadeIn(300);
            return false;                   
        }

    });
```

I have added some snippets of my code related to submit the form. Can you please guide me if I m going wrong somewhere if there is some binding problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the `submitHandler` inside of your validate code.

```
$('#signup-form').validate({
   rules: {
     'firstname': { required: true },
     'lastname': { required: true },
     'email': {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: {
           url: siteurl+'ajax/checkemail',
           type: 'post'
        }
     }
   },

   messages: {
     'firstname': { required: 'Please enter your first name' },
     'lastname': { required: 'Please enter your last name' },
     'email': {
        required: 'Please enter your email address',
        email: 'Your email address is invalid',
        remote: 'The email you chose is already in use'
     }
   },

   errorLabelContainer: $(".fail-message"),

   submitHandler: function(form) {
      ...WHAT YOU WANT TO HAPPEN WHEN THE FORM IS SUBMITTED...
      form.submit();
   }
});
```

You shouldn't be attaching anything to the submit button manually; The validation plug-in handles this all for you.

Here's the official documentation for the jQuery Validation plug-in: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation. Tons of good information and examples there.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your quick reply. I am actually new to JQuery and it overall concepts. Can you please be specific or give me some post/docs to refer?

Comment: it's also worth noting that using $('form').valid() doesn't apply the rules set in $('form').validate() as the .valid() method also requires those rules

Comment: Since it's a signup form, I need to do the validation, once successful I want to submit my form. So should I just write,            $('#signup-form').submit in the submitHandler: function ??                                            submitHandler: function(form) { 
      ...WHAT YOU WANT TO HAPPEN WHEN THE FORM IS SUBMITTED...
      form.submit();
   }

Comment: If all you want to do is submit your form on a success, all you would need is `form.submit();` in the submitHandler. When the form is submitted, the error checking will take place and (if no errors occur) the script in the `submitHandler` will run.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for being so kind but when I am not attaching to my submit button, its not working at all. :( It's showing a '#' in my ul path. This is what I added to my code as you said,       
 .
        .
        .
  'code'     errorLabelContainer: $(".fail-message"),

   submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
   }  
  }); 'code'

And I commented this section of code.
'code'
/* $("#signup-ok-btn").click(function(){           
              $("#signup-form").submit();
              return false;         
             }); */ 'code'

Comment: Hi Michael, 
Thank you very much. It worked in Firefox version 3.6. I hope so it works for IE also. Thanks a ton once again.

Comment: No problem. Please remember to accept this answer if your problem has been resolved.

Comment: Hi Michael, your solution is working fine for Firefox. But it is not supported by IE . So basically, my 50% problem is solved. Can you suggest me what can be error for IE ?? It is submitting the form without validation saving default values in my database.

Comment: Make sure you submit button isn't named `submit`. I've seen this cause problems with `form.submit()` before. Try changing the name of the submit button to `btnSubmit` or something.

Comment: I am not using any button. Its a anchor image. I tried keeping name same as id and different from id, but in both the cases it still submits the form without validation. Below is my html code for the signup button.
<a id="signup-ok-btn" class="ok-btn" href="#"></a>

Comment: That image is not going to invoke the submit functionality of a form and is semantically incorrect. You should be using a submit button.

Comment: I tried modifying my code as shown below, still it didn't worked!! Any idea what can be the problem ?                                       <input id="signup-ok-btn" type="submit" name="signup-ok-btn" class="ok-btn" href="#" value=""/>
Same problem of no validation, but success in form submission.

Comment: Finally it worked on IE 8 by updating my jquery.validate plugin. I did not even had to change my submit button to type=submit. I have just use an anchor image.